# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable - when trying to .send_keys() to text boxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

self.driver.get("website")


self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("mylivechat_collapsed").click()

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Name'").send_keys(self.names)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email']").send_keys(self.email)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='Type your message']").send_keys(self.message)
```

Hi,

I am trying to enter text into 3 input boxes. Selenium manages to find the 3 boxes, however it for some reason returns an error (`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`) when I try to use the `send_keys()` method. The text box **is visible and clickable**.

I have tried using `WebDriverWait` (along with other waits like `times.sleep` and `driver.implicitly-wait()`) and `ActionChains`, but they don't work.

[Email input HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gWfw.png)

How can I fix this? **Any help is greatly appreciated :)**

Comment: Add the HTML around the element that is returning the error.

Comment: @Jortega I added the Email text box element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to debug this together:

1. **Are you sure that your variables are set at the time of assignment**, that is, self.name, etc?
2. Are you using any IDE that you could help you debug and can utilize breakpoints so you could step through the code? Because if not, I'd try to isolate your problem to just setting a static value, such as not retrieving the value from your class variables at the same time.
   In your case, use:

   self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_path_here).send_keys("Jane Doe")
3. If you have control over the source code, try adding ID to your element (ID are suppose to be unique), and use .find_element_by_id selector instead of xpath. If you can't put ID, try (at least for debugging purposes) use full_xpath. Generally **try avoiding using full_xpath** as it is prone to go out of sync with smallest webpage structure changes, but for debugging - it is a great resource).

Comment: Thank you! I used the full_xpath and it works now :).